# CMIS Relationships --> List of objects (documents or folder) by type of relationship

Tags: relationship, cmis

Good Morning.

I have several types of relationships created in a custom model. 
Using CMIS, is there any way to search for associations by type? In order to get all the source or target documents or folders that use this association?

I evaluated the use of query in CMIS, in order to obtain the ids of the documents, but it is not possible to use query in relationships, (if I understand well).

For example, I have 4 processes A; B, C and D, which has several documents associated each.

Process A ----> type of relationship ---> sc.fatura

Process B ----> type of relationship ---> sc.contrato

Process C ----> type of relationship ---> sc.acta

Process D ----> type of relationship ---> sc.fatura

When searching for a contract, you would get all the documents associated with Process B. when you searched for sc.fatura, you would get all the documents in process A and D.

Is it possible to do something similar using CMIS?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when filtering results you'd try to use an OperationContext. I thought there might be a way to tell the OC to filter to a specific relationship type, but it does not look like it. So I think the best you can do is filter it yourself by checking the relationship's type ID, like this:

```
Session session = getSession();

// Dump the object's associations
OperationContext oc = new OperationContextImpl();
oc.setIncludeRelationships(IncludeRelationships.SOURCE);

Document sourceDoc = (Document) session.getObject(session.createObjectId(sourceObjectId), oc);
List<Relationship> relList = sourceDoc.getRelationships();
System.out.println("Associations of objectId: " + sourceObjectId);
for (Relationship rel : relList) {
    // In this example I only want relationships of type sc:exampleRel1
    if ("R:sc:exampleRel1".equals(rel.getRelationshipType().getId())) {
        System.out.println("    " + rel.getTarget().getId());
    }
}
```